# Why does route not compile when returning non-Responder error in Rocket?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket, reqwest

The Rocket documentation says this:

> If the error type `E` does not implement `Responder`, then the error is simply logged to the console, using its `Debug` implementation, and a 500 error is returned to the client.

I have a route with this signature, but it does not compile:

```
fn gmap() -> Result<String, Box<std::error::Error>>
```

```
the trait `Responder<'_, '_>` is not implemented for `Box<dyn StdError>`
```

Didn't the documentation just tell me that the error does not need to implement `Responder`?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation above is correct... for version 0.4 of Rocket. The trait signature in your error indicates you're using 0.5 (release candidate) which does *not* offer this functionality. You should refer to the [0.5 Guide](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/) for your information if that's what you're using.

The reason this changed is to allow Rocket to compile on the stable channel. Version 0.4 required nightly for, among other reasons, the ability to *specialize* the response for error types that implemented `Responder` while still supporting non-`Responder` error types.